# X is not associated to Y (Sequelize / ExpressJS)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am new to NodeJS with express and Sequelize. When I want to create a book rental, the console gives me "Book is not associated to Rent".

When I migrate the tables to the sql database, the id's are in their place and my seeders are working.

Do you have the solution?

Error: EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: Book is not associated to Rent!

Book model :

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Book extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.belongsTo(models.Author);
      this.belongsTo(models.Category);
      this.hasMany(models.Rent, {
        foreignKey: 'id'
      });
    }
  }
  Book.init(
    {
      authorId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      categoryId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      title: DataTypes.STRING,
      description: DataTypes.TEXT,
      amount: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Book'
    }
  );
  return Book;
};
```

Rent model:

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Rent extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.belongsTo(models.User);
      this.belongsTo(models.Book);
    }
  }
  Rent.init(
    {
      userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      bookId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      in: DataTypes.DATE,
      back: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Rent'
    }
  );
  return Rent;
};
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing new code with old code. It states that rent has a foreign key from book table with key bookId.

**Old Code**

```
 this.hasMany(models.Rent, {
        foreignKey: 'id'
      });
```

**New Code**

```
 this.hasMany(models.Rent, {
        foreignKey: 'bookId'
      });
```